# How to configure python tornado application to give back a crossdomain.xml?

Tags: python, tornado

So as far as I know first step shoud be create some response class in main application which is link with some url pattern. For example:

```
(r'/crossdomain.xml', GrahhHandler)
```

then in second step we should some way return crossdomail.xml document when we call GrahhHanler get function

```
class GrahhHandler (web.RequestHandler):
    def get():
        return self.render('crossdomain.xml')
```

But I have 500: Internal Server Error after configuring GrahhHandler such way

TypeError: get() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /crossdomain.xml (127.0.0.1) 25.00ms

Please help me to configure GrahhHandler to get back a real crossdomain.xml

Comment: You forgot to add `self` argument to `get` method.

Comment: sorry I fogot to add self in get method arguments. I fixed the several error but now method return me html with crossdomain.xml nodes. But not clear xml

Answer (score 0):

Set the proper `content-type` header for `xml` just before the `render()` call:

```
self.set_header("Content-Type", "text/xml")
```